# PyPI packaging, namespace packages and subpackaging problems

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, namespace-package

I've uploaded my personnal generic functions called `ofunctions` to github in order to share them between my projects, and having separate CI and coverage tests. Link to github project [here](https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions).

So far so good, I have a package called `ofunctions` which has several subpacakges like `ofunctions.network`.

I want to be able to install subpackages without having to install the whole package, ie `pip install ofunctions.network`.
So I've created a single `setup.py` file that creates the necessary dist files to upload on PyPI.

My problem:

Whenever I use `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, it generates the full `ofunctions` package and a package for each subpackage, but:

- source packages like `ofunctions.network-0.5.0.tar.gz` only contain the subpackage (expected behavior)
- wheel packages like `ofunctions.network-0.5.0-py3-non-any.whl` which contain the whole package (unexpected behavior)

The wheel packages contain the whole `ofunctions` library including all subpackages which obviously should only contain the same subpackage as the source dist files.

Can anybody have a look at my `setup.py` file and tell me why the sdist and wheel files don't contain strictly the same subpackages only ?

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# This file is part of ofunctions package

"""
Namespace packaging here

# Make sure we declare an __init__.py file as namespace holder in the package root containing the following

try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    from pkgutil import extend_path
    __path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
"""

import codecs
import os

import pkg_resources
import setuptools


def get_metadata(package_file):
    """
    Read metadata from pacakge file
    """

    def _read(_package_file):
        here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        with codecs.open(os.path.join(here, _package_file), 'r') as fp:
            return fp.read()

    _metadata = {}

    for line in _read(package_file).splitlines():
        if line.startswith('__version__'):
            delim = '"' if '"' in line else "'"
            _metadata['version'] = line.split(delim)[1]
        if line.startswith('__description__'):
            delim = '"' if '"' in line else "'"
            _metadata['description'] = line.split(delim)[1]
    return _metadata


def parse_requirements(filename):
    """
    There is a parse_requirements function in pip but it keeps changing import path
    Let's build a simple one
    """
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as requirements_txt:
            install_requires = [
                str(requirement)
                for requirement
                in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(requirements_txt)
            ]
        return install_requires
    except OSError:
        print('WARNING: No requirements.txt file found as "{}". Please check path or create an empty one'
              .format(filename))


def get_long_description(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as readme_file:
        _long_description = readme_file.read()
    return _long_description


#  ######### ACTUAL SCRIPT ENTRY POINT

NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME = 'ofunctions'
namespace_package_path = os.path.abspath(NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME)
namespace_package_file = os.path.join(namespace_package_path, '__init__.py')
metadata = get_metadata(namespace_package_file)
requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(namespace_package_path, 'requirements.txt'))

# Generic namespace package
setuptools.setup(
    name=NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME,
    namespace_packages=[NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME],
    packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(include=['ofunctions.*']),
    version=metadata['version'],
    install_requires=requirements,
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Topic :: Software Development",
        "Topic :: System",
        "Topic :: System :: Operating System",
        "Topic :: System :: Shells",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: FreeBSD",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: NetBSD",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: OpenBSD",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
    description=metadata['description'],
    author='NetInvent - Orsiris de Jong',
    author_email='contact@netinvent.fr',
    url='https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions',
    keywords=['network', 'bisection', 'logging'],
    long_description=get_long_description('README.md'),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    python_requires='>=3.5',
    # namespace packages don't work well with zipped eggs
    # ref https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/
    zip_safe=False
)

for package in setuptools.find_namespace_packages(include=['ofunctions.*']):
    package_path = os.path.abspath(package.replace('.', os.sep))
    package_file = os.path.join(package_path, '__init__.py')
    metadata = get_metadata(package_file)
    requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(package_path, 'requirements.txt'))
    print(package_path)
    print(package_file)
    print(metadata)
    print(requirements)

    setuptools.setup(
        name=package,
        namespace_packages=[NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME],
        packages=[package],
        package_data={package: ['__init__.py']},
        version=metadata['version'],
        install_requires=requirements,
        classifiers=[
            "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
            "Intended Audience :: Developers",
            "Topic :: Software Development",
            "Topic :: System",
            "Topic :: System :: Operating System",
            "Topic :: System :: Shells",
            "Programming Language :: Python",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: FreeBSD",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: NetBSD",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: OpenBSD",
            "Operating System :: Microsoft",
            "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
        ],
        description=metadata['description'],
        author='NetInvent - Orsiris de Jong',
        author_email='contact@netinvent.fr',
        url='https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions',
        keywords=['network', 'bisection', 'logging'],
        long_description=get_long_description('README.md'),
        long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
        python_requires='>=3.5',
        # namespace packages don't work well with zipped eggs
        # ref https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/
        zip_safe=False
    )
```

Thanks 8-|

Comment: You probably need to create different projects, containing a `setup.py` each. I do not thinkg I have ever seen a project with a `setup.py` containing multiple calls to `setuptools.setup` that was working as expected.

Comment: I actually saw your post on https://discuss.python.org/t/use-case-supported-2-namespace-packages-in-single-source-repo-with-1-setup-py/5440/5 which insipred me. I'd be damned to make a setup.py file for every subpackage. I'll still search a bit. Pretty sure I have to remove some temp files somewhere so built packages stay clean. I'll report back if I happen to find the solution ;)

Comment: I forgot I had written this, haha! -- I'd need to re-read all this, I don't remember the whole thing. But one key thing, in that other discussion the code I suggested runs `setuptools.setup` only once in the `setup.py`. -- If you manage to create a minimal reproducible example [mre] I can probably help.

Comment: I did manage to come up with a working implementation (see my answer below). But I noticed `setuptools.setup()` never cleans the build directory, and if I happen to put a big file out of nowhere inside, next build will contain that file. Isn't that somehow a bug that should be reported to setuptools ? Btw, thanks for your help and your former implementation ;)

Comment: OK, If it works, it works. -- One more note though: Maybe if you are worried about having to write too many `setup.py` files, you could write a script that generates those `setup.py` files (or better `setup.cfg`), and keep things more "standard".

Comment: You're right, I was trying to be lazy... in the end I got more work ;) But that problem with non empty build dirs bloated by previous build files (regardless of namespace packages I think) worries me more now. Not an setuptools expert. Do you think I should file a bug report ?

Comment: I think it's by design that the build directory is not deleted every time. I think I remember seeing discussions on that topic. Might be it is about reusing previously built artifacts to speed up the global build process.

Comment: I think in your case, I would write a script that creates setup.py files in each of the subdirectories (i.e. 1 per distribution package), and calls them all one after the other (`subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'sdist'])` I guess). No need to create monster `setup.py` files that would only cause issues down the line.

Comment: At the end, it would still endup in the same build dir, so I'd still have to empty that one between each setup.py run.

Comment: Depends... In that case, it depends how you organize the project directory structure. It's all a matter of compromises. I do not have one right answer.

Comment: Indeed, but then I'd ne better off making a full project out of every subpackage, which is overkill to me. Anyway, I'll use build dir clean solution. Big thanks for tour time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I think I found the problem.
The `build` directory isn't cleaned between setuptools runs.

Worse, build directory is *never* cleaned unless you manually remove it, so old build files may endup in newer wheel package builds, even on single package builds I think.

I added a function `clear_package_build_path()` before running `setuptools.setup()` run that just cleans the `build/lib/package` dir.
Now my wheel files build with only the necessary files, no bloating anymore.

For instance here's the full working code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# This file is part of ofunctions package

"""
Namespace packaging here

# Make sure we declare an __init__.py file as namespace holder in the package root containing the following

try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    from pkgutil import extend_path
    __path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
"""

import codecs
import os
import shutil

import pkg_resources
import setuptools


def get_metadata(package_file):
    """
    Read metadata from package file
    """

    def _read(_package_file):
        here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        with codecs.open(os.path.join(here, _package_file), 'r') as fp:
            return fp.read()

    _metadata = {}

    for line in _read(package_file).splitlines():
        if line.startswith('__version__'):
            delim = '"' if '"' in line else "'"
            _metadata['version'] = line.split(delim)[1]
        if line.startswith('__description__'):
            delim = '"' if '"' in line else "'"
            _metadata['description'] = line.split(delim)[1]
    return _metadata


def parse_requirements(filename):
    """
    There is a parse_requirements function in pip but it keeps changing import path
    Let's build a simple one
    """
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as requirements_txt:
            install_requires = [
                str(requirement)
                for requirement
                in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(requirements_txt)
            ]
        return install_requires
    except OSError:
        print('WARNING: No requirements.txt file found as "{}". Please check path or create an empty one'
              .format(filename))


def get_long_description(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as readme_file:
        _long_description = readme_file.read()
    return _long_description


def clear_package_build_path(package_rel_path):
    """
    We need to clean build path, but setuptools will wait for build/lib/package_name so we need to create that
    """
    build_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('build', 'lib', package_rel_path))
    try:
        # We need to use shutil.rmtree() instead of os.remove() since the latter implementation
        # produces "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied"
        shutil.rmtree('build')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('build path: {} does not exist'.format(build_path))
    # Now we need to create the 'build/lib/package/subpackage' path so setuptools won't fail
    os.makedirs(build_path)


#  ######### ACTUAL SCRIPT ENTRY POINT

NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME = 'ofunctions'
namespace_package_path = os.path.abspath(NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME)
namespace_package_file = os.path.join(namespace_package_path, '__init__.py')
metadata = get_metadata(namespace_package_file)
requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(namespace_package_path, 'requirements.txt'))

# First lets make sure build path is clean (avoiding namespace package pollution in subpackages)
# Clean build dir before every run so we don't make cumulative wheel files
clear_package_build_path(NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME)

# Generic namespace package
setuptools.setup(
    name=NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME,
    namespace_packages=[NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME],
    packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(include=['ofunctions.*']),
    version=metadata['version'],
    install_requires=requirements,
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Topic :: Software Development",
        "Topic :: System",
        "Topic :: System :: Operating System",
        "Topic :: System :: Shells",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: FreeBSD",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: NetBSD",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: OpenBSD",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
    description=metadata['description'],
    author='NetInvent - Orsiris de Jong',
    author_email='contact@netinvent.fr',
    url='https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions',
    keywords=['network', 'bisection', 'logging'],
    long_description=get_long_description('README.md'),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    python_requires='>=3.5',
    # namespace packages don't work well with zipped eggs
    # ref https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/
    zip_safe=False
)



for package in setuptools.find_namespace_packages(include=['ofunctions.*']):
    rel_package_path = package.replace('.', os.sep)
    package_path = os.path.abspath(rel_package_path)
    package_file = os.path.join(package_path, '__init__.py')
    metadata = get_metadata(package_file)
    requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(package_path, 'requirements.txt'))
    print(package_path)
    print(package_file)
    print(metadata)
    print(requirements)

    # Again, we need to clean build paths between runs
    clear_package_build_path(rel_package_path)

    setuptools.setup(
        name=package,
        namespace_packages=[NAMESPACE_PACKAGE_NAME],
        packages=[package],
        package_data={package: ['__init__.py']},
        version=metadata['version'],
        install_requires=requirements,
        classifiers=[
            "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
            "Intended Audience :: Developers",
            "Topic :: Software Development",
            "Topic :: System",
            "Topic :: System :: Operating System",
            "Topic :: System :: Shells",
            "Programming Language :: Python",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: FreeBSD",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: NetBSD",
            "Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD :: OpenBSD",
            "Operating System :: Microsoft",
            "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
        ],
        description=metadata['description'],
        author='NetInvent - Orsiris de Jong',
        author_email='contact@netinvent.fr',
        url='https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions',
        keywords=['network', 'bisection', 'logging'],
        long_description=get_long_description('README.md'),
        long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
        python_requires='>=3.5',
        # namespace packages don't work well with zipped eggs
        # ref https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/
        zip_safe=False
    )
```

As a side node, I noticed that `os.remove()` will fail with `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied` from time to time because `os.remove()` waits for all handles to be closed, which can take time because of garbage collector (AFAIK). Using `shutil.rmtree()` does work in any case.